# Set collation and locale for a column in create table statement using Java/JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, icu

I am using PostgreSQL and want to create my database schema using JPA/Hibernate directly. In PostgreSQL I cannot (unfortunately) set the database default collation into ICU based collations, i.e. the following does not work:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE 'und-x-icu' LC_CTYPE 'und-x-icu' TEMPLATE 'template0';
```

The reason can be read from this thread:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/3366.1498183854%40sss.pgh.pa.us#3366.1498183854@sss.pgh.pa.us

This means that I need to set the default collation when ever I create a table in the database. This would mean that the CREATE TABLE statements should be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    my_column TEXT COLLATE "und-x-icu"
);
```

How can I do this using JPA annotations, or similar standard method?

Comment: You can try to use `@Column(name = "my_column", columnDefinition = "TEXT COLLATE \"und-x-icu\" ")`